# utf8_encode and accented characters dilemma?

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, diacritics

I am facing a paradox in decoding with `utf8_encode` decode. I have a MySQL database with uft8 collation and whose fields have the `utf8_general` coding. I have my php file in utf8, and in my HTML pages I have specified in the header the utf8 charset.

My problem is that when I select from my table a field containing accented characters (like *èçò ùé*) and echo that to the browser, I get strange characters.

To resolve my problem, I have to echo `$description=utf8_encode($imm['description'])`.

My question is why can’t I do the echo directly without having to use `uft8_encode` every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll just guess that your database *connection* is not set to UTF-8.
See [SET NAMES utf8 in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159434/set-names-utf8-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

you need to specify the header using php to be utf-8. also make sure that the format of the chars is utf-8 before storing in the db because utf_encode encodes an ISO-8859-1 string to UTF-8, which most likely means that the chars are being stored as ISO-8859-1  in s a utf-8 table.

make sure that you convert those chars in utf-8 before storing them in the db and then echo should not be a problem at all.

Source: had the exact same problem myself.