# Mixing UTF8 and latin1_bin fields in MySQL with PHP

Tags: mysql, encoding, mamp

On a database I'll have to store names and such in UTF8, and hashes in latin1_bin. I called `SET NAMES utf8`, but I noticed that it corrupted the latin1 fields when I tried to read them (I was able to write them just fine). Which is odd, since if I understood correctly that query is only about *sending* data to the server, not *receiving* it.

phpMyAdmin displays broken data too.

Any clue about what I might be doing wrong?

(using MAMP 1.9.6)

edit: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159434/set-names-utf8-in-mysql/2159463#2159463) answer specifies this is also the charset used to send data back to the client. I'm getting confused: what's the point of specifying the charset of a column if that will be ignored anyway?

edit:
excerpt from the column definition:

```
  `tok` char(64) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `sal` char(16) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
...
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_roman_ci ;
```

excerpt from queries:

```
SELECT tok,sal FROM user WHERE id=4 LIMIT 1
```

.

```
INSERT INTO user (tok, sal) VALUES (x'1387ea0c22277d3000bd23241c357e3a9ba45a2e28f50581d63a73bf785a7458a95cca4de27d0a86588f5bdfa94415d6a255c2c0379ebc2f00dacba03ae6b866', x'8fca28a592c29f245ff0a3ba5f97420c')
```

Comment: How are your hash columns defined, and what do your read/write queries look like?

Comment: @Jon: updated with excerpts from the columns and the queries

Comment: How do you treat the incoming values when reading them? This should work: `echo bin2hex(iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $sal))`.

Comment: @Jon: I just get empty strings if I try to do that.

Comment: @Jon: `mb_convert_encoding` converts it to *something* instead, but still not the right value.

Comment: Doing the other way around, i.e. removing `SET NAMES`, then converting from latin1 to utf8 when retrieving the utf8 data, kind of worked. Of course it's highly undesirable, so the problem stands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change your table definition to use MySql's [`BINARY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/binary-varbinary.html) type, which is the perfect fit for this kind of data:

> The BINARY and VARBINARY types are similar to CHAR and VARCHAR, except
>   that they contain binary strings rather than nonbinary strings. That
>   is, they contain byte strings rather than character strings. This
>   means that they have no character set, and sorting and comparison are
>   based on the numeric values of the bytes in the values.

The column definitions would become:

```
`tok` binary(64) NOT NULL,
`sal` binary(16) NOT NULL,
```

Answer (score -1):

`set names ...` only sets the character set of the connection (of the client side only!) for both sending and receiving the data. It is not related to the encoding of the fields in the database! It is only related to the encoding which you use as a client to the database, e.g. in PHP. The database engine will always convert the encoding between the encoding in tables to the encoding specified in `set names ...` query.

So in table definition you just specify encoding for each field as you need, and you don't change anything in the way how you used the `set names ...` command - it just remains the same as before.

Comment: I don't get it: how can I mix different encodings then?

Comment: @lohoris, just by specifying the encoding in the `create table` or `alter table` command. Then, during the client connection, the 2 different encodings will be converted to the connection encoding specified in `set names ...` (that implies that the connection encoding must be able to embrace all encodings used, so if you have very different encodings you might need to use utf-8 as connection encoding).

Comment: why was this post downvoted? I use this approach many years and it works. It's part of a good culture to leave comment when downvoting.

Answer (score -1):

Leaving `SET NAMES` on, and the `INSERT` query intact, I changed the `SELECT` query to:

```
SELECT BINARY(tok) AS tok, BINARY(sal) AS sal FROM user WHERE id=4 LIMIT 1
```

i.e. I casted the hash fields to binary.

While this worked, I'll leave this open in case someone provides a (perhaps more correct?) alternative.

Comment: I thought that `sal binary(16) NOT NULL` on the table definition would be more correct but that it wouldn't make a difference here. Can you check if it does? If it solves the problem, that's IMHO "the" correct solution.

Comment: @Jon: yeah, that worked, thanks :) (would you post it as an answer so I can accept it?)