# How can I convert this (′) character to html entities using php?

Tags: php

I want to make this character (′) html entity for storing in my database using php. I am using MySQL databse. I use:

```
$string = "HTML5′s placeholder Attribute";
$newStr = htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES);
echo $newStr;
```

the above code prints the following

```
HTML5&acirc;?&sup2;s placeholder Attribute
```

How can I make this (′) character an HTML entity?

Comment: That character's not a special character in HTML, you shouldn't escape it as such. Use your database driver's string escaping functions, or better yet a database API that gives you parameter interpolation. (Not knowing what database you're using and what libraries are available in your PHP install, it's not really possible to make a less vague answer.)

Comment: @Inerdial I am using MySQL database

Comment: Then the simplest solution is using [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), and using the same encoding (preferrably UTF-8) end to end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/htmlentities) here, as that specific quote thingy does not need escaping normally. And you also need to specifiy the charset, as you otherwise get those Latin-1 equivalent escapes:

```
echo htmlentities("′", ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

Should either get you `&#8242;` or `&prime;` as result.

Comment: How i can convert this from a string, like this string "HTML5′s placeholder Attribute".

Comment: You use your string as first parameter, like in your original example.

Comment: I use my string as first parameter. it prints nothing.

Comment: No, it's not an output function. Add `echo` before it.

Comment: that's code working fine echo htmlentities("HTML5′s placeholder Attribute", ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"); . But when i store my string to db $str = htmlentities("HTML5′s placeholder Attribute", ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"); . It stores an empty value

Comment: See what @Inerdial wrote. If this is just an elaborate database charset workaround, then don't do it. Use [`SET NAMES UTF8`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159434/set-names-utf8-in-mysql) and the right table schemes for mysql rather. Also use `mysql_error()` to find the reason for failed querys and inserts.

Comment: I execute this SET NAMES UTF8 to my database. If the string has no (′). The string stores in the database successfully. But If string has (′). The query stores a blank value. Please Help me