# storing and retrieve special characters mysql

Tags: java, php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to select mysql query with foreign language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9174881/how-to-select-mysql-query-with-foreign-language)

I was unable to store characters like `★` or `♥` beside text  in mysql table ,but I change the collation to `utf8-bin` i can store them now but when i retrieve the text it displays `?` character , is there any way to store these characters along with normal characters and retrieve them ? and does changing the collation affect the accuracy of searching on this text ?

Comment: Many duplicates in the "related" column and in the search and on Google.... Also "can't retrieve" is not a good description of the problem. What exactly happens?

Comment: Please see this,
 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/633762/special-characters-in-php-mysql

Comment: @Pekka when i retrieve the text it displays ? character .

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure everything is in utf8:

- The database
- The database connection (something like `$db->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');` in PDO / PHP after making the connection)
- Your php document if you are using php
- Your html output

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. You need to issue these queries before retrieving data from database.

```
mysql_query("set character_set_server='utf8'");
mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");
```

And before echoing out the HTML to a web page, set the page charset to UTF-8.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using a htmlentities() function. It will encode all applicable characters to html entities.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: This is a terrible solution. This issue can be solved without resorting to stuff like this.