# insert korean characters to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to insert some phrases to MySQL

the first field is english and the second one is korean. the problem each time I insert the value from my PHP script it's shows in the MYSQL like this. `&#54617;&#44368;`

However, if I insert the the same korean value from PhpMyAdmin it will works, so the problem from the php script. I've found in the web that I have to change the `Collation` in MySQL?

Any help ?

```
<?

//*---------------------------------------------------------*\\
//* if POST
//*---------------------------------------------------------*\\
if($_POST['addphrase'])
{
    $SQL = "INSERT INTO `sd_phrases` VALUES(NULL,?,?)";
    $db = new db();
    $db->execute($SQL,$_POST['english'],$_POST['korean']);
    $box = new true_box();
    $box->init('PLease Wait....','index.php?action=phrases');
    die();
}

?>
<form method="post">
<center>
    <table class="horz">
    <tr><th colspan="2">Add a new Phrase</th></tr>
    <tr><td>English Phrase</td><td><div align="left"><input type="text" size="80" name="english"></div>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>Korean Phrase</td><td><div align="left"><input type="text" size="80" name="korean"></div>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Add" name="addphrase"></td></tr>
    </table>
</center>
</form>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show the relevant PHP code?

Comment: @dusan Sure. just refresh the page

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The collation should be set to `utf8_unicode_ci` as Danack57 says.

You should use just UTF8 as your character encoding scheme.

```
default-character-set = utf8
```

After opening each mysql connection, execute `set names utf8;`
Read [this](http://www.bluebox.net/news/2009/07/mysql_encoding/)

Comment: I've set the collation to `euckr_korean_ci ` before posting the question, but from the php it converted to `&#54617;&#44368;`

Comment: Have you tried using UTF8. The unicode characters should show up right, when you fetch it. I have edited my answer.

Comment: For the love of all that is holy - just use UTF8 and utf8_unicode_ci as the collation. Using a language specific character set or collation is inevitably going to fail.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the way the html page is reporting the encoding to the users browser. I suspect one is reporting as utf8 and the other is reporting as some other encoding. So when the values got posted back from the browser, the are encoded differently. Php does not do the encoding, it more or less takes what the forms post to it. Load with pages and check the encoding in the web browseraan see if you can get the two page to report the same encoding using meta tags.

Comment: I'd suggest hard-coding the variables that are being inserted so that you can check that the SQL is working first, and then debug that the form is being submitted as UTF8 separately.