# Inserting data to Mysql in Malayalam

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I have done a code in PHP to insert data into MySql in malayalam. When I insert data, It becomes English in database.. I have set charset to utf-8 in my code and in data base utf8 general_ci..please anyone give answer..thanks in advance

Comment: Read this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/internationalization-localization.html

Comment: Have u use my code & checked it...

Answer (score 1):

You can give this simple code

```
SELECT * FROM dictionary WHERE malayalam = 'ആകാശം'
```

This code will work fine in phpmysql,also you can refer this link

[Press this link for your clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9174881/how-to-select-mysql-query-with-foreign-language)

Answer (score 1):

1) Add the code beginning of the php page
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

2) Make sure your database & tables are on Collation utf8_general_ci

3) Use the database connection code:
$conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $password, $database);
$conn->set_charset("utf8");

4) Then try insert query and retrieve query using $conn handler,
ie:      $q_newspage="SELECT * FROM news GROUP BY id DESC LIMIT 8";
         $qresult_newspage=$conn->query("$q_newspage");

Thanks

Comment: thanks for mentioning collation : we generally don't set this and it becomes the swedish one by default.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to set charset as `utf8` in META tag

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

For [More](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations#quicklookup)

And in mysql as

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

Then you can insert in to db as,

```
INSERT INTO tableName (name) VALUES ('രാകേഷ്');
```