# Updating mysql table (UTF8) using form method

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update a table query UTF8 using a form. Its displays in form but not able to edit. Please let me know what the fault in query?

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
require_once("./includeadmin/membersite_config.php");
require_once("./includeadmin/membersite_config_editorial.php");
include("database1.php");
if(!$fgmembersite->CheckLogin())
{
$fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("index.php");
exit;
}


$idi = $_POST['id2'];
$sql = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");

if (!$sql) {
die ('Could not connect!: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("nam33_articles", $sql);
mysql_query("UPDATE editorial SET date = '$_POST[date]', tag =         
'$_POST[tag]', title = '$_POST[title]', small = '$_POST[small]', image = 
'$_POST[image]', smallimage = '$_POST[smallimage]', english = 
'$_POST[english]', full = '$_POST[full]') WHERE id_user = '$idi'");
?>
```

Comment: It gives any error?

Comment: Its not giving any error. the table is not updating.

Comment: Can you use query line from my answer and echo it so we got the query and find the error on that query.

Comment: its all content converted to question marks. No error showing. Edited parts echoing successfully. But all content converted to question marks

Comment: are you use other than English language for input field?

Comment: yes... malayalam

Comment: Okay so question mark display on query or database if your query contains correct string and database contain ??? then you need to change Collation from database to utf16_bin

Comment: I changed the collation to utf16_bin...now its showing some Japanese characters.

Comment: can you try this collation utf8 general_ci...

Comment: refre this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20987358/inserting-data-to-mysql-in-malayalam

Comment: I changed. Echoing showing correctly. But the table not upadating.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181862/discussion-between-sachin-and-chathan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your query parameters and set utf8.

```
mysql_query("set names 'utf8'",$sql);
$query = "UPDATE editorial SET date = '".$_POST['date']."', tag = '".$_POST['tag']."', title = '".utf8_encode($_POST['title'])."', small = '".utf8_encode($_POST['small'])."', image = '".$_POST['image']."', smallimage = '".$_POST['smallimage']."', english = '".$_POST['english']."', full = '".utf8_encode($_POST['full'])."' WHERE id_user = '$idi'";
mysql_query($query);
```