# MySQL, enter ê -like symbols into fields without getting a blank field

Tags: mysql

I tried to enter a word "hên" (is an elvish word) into MySQL, but I am getting a blank field. It supports other languages, but shows empty fields for ô, ŷ etc.

How can I get MySQL read those symbols, if possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Use a proper collation.

Comment: Change the collation to whatever you're putting the data in as.  Most prefer UTF8.

Comment: set everything you can to UTF-8, UTF8, or utf8_general_ci

Comment: Excuse me juergen, what do you mean? I didn't get it :(

Comment: @DanFromGermany, Thanks, that worked for mysql! Although, now when I enter a value into a field through php, it shows me blank again.

Comment: Remember to tell you connection to use UTF-8. In PHP you do it like this, after connecting: `mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8")` (`mysql_set_charset("utf8");` for deprecated type connection)

Answer (score 0):

set everything you can to UTF-8, UTF8, or utf8_general_ci

You might also use `SET NAMES utf8;` see this link: [SET NAMES utf8 in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159434/set-names-utf8-in-mysql)

in your html use this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

In PHP, on top of everything, use this:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

Comment: Okay, here's what I've figured out so far. When I use php to directly enter value like hên into table, it works even without:
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); and mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8"), as Max pointed out above. But when I use Jquery (through ajax) to insert that value through php file, I get blank field no matter what I add to php file or event html utf-8 charset. Note, that when I use ordinary words, it does work.

Comment: make sure you saved the scripts and files under UTF-8 Encoding, what text editor do you use? also if you upload, use binary upload.

Comment: I tried everything (that I was suggested to), but won't work. This is my ajax function body from JQuery after adding a few things: https://gist.github.com/davit/0c0797fa61c929758c37  Oh and, I use Phpstorm and Webstorm.

Comment: remove `header:('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8')` from the ajax

Comment: I am so sorry. The problem was in passing a wrong element ID in ajax functon..I apologize! It works without specifying any unicodes; even without: <meta charset="UTF-8">. So again, sorry and thanks for your time!