# what could mean this character

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I have a web, all encode is set to utf-8, but sometimes, i can see this character � and now, i'm having problems because i want to make an ajax request and if this character exist, the response is null.

I really don't understand because for example, in this image, you can see text that come from the same table, showing ok and with this character.
I thought that was the encode of the php file, and change it to utf-8, ansi, etc., but it doesn't matter, the result sometimes was worse

could be the browser from where the data is saved to the database? i don't think so but i have to ask

so, how can i deal with this? i even tried using `utf8_encode` and decode but it was worse
i really don't know what else to try
hope you can help me
thanks
http://uhma.mx/uploads/images/character.png

Comment: Check that your files are encoded with UTF-8 without BOM. Ensure that your PHP is using UTF-8 by doing: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`. If the result is coming in from an external source, such as a DB, check the charset/collation there. That's a start. Also check whether the original string includes the proper character, or does it have that gibberish.

Comment: Are all of the following set to utf-8: php file, html output (by html meta tag or php `header()`, database connection and possibly database collation? Have any of those ever been set to another charset? This could explain why some entries are displayed correctly and others not.

Comment: @Marcel that really should be an answer :-)

Comment: It felt as more of a comment. Answer submitted.

Comment: I feel cheated. The people that install the web told me that everything was in utf-8, after reading your comments, i ask them for access to the DB, and when i run `show create database dbname` it say it is in `latin1`, now i don't know what to do. if i change the DB charset some data could be lost? or should i change the code charset in `meta` and `header` to latin1? what is the best solution?

Comment: "Install[ed] the web". Have fun waiting for that installation process to finish.

Comment: jajajaja...that was funny, ah?, really men, i'm stuck and looking for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch all data that are being displayed in `UTF-8`, [assuming mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159434/set-names-utf8-in-mysql):

- set encoding on all columns to `utf-8`
- execute `SET NAMES 'utf-8'` and  `SET CHARSET 'utf-8'` as soon as you open DB connecton

If you need to convert charset from database default (usually `latin1`), there's already [great answer for that here on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6115705/1149736).

Additionally send `Content-Type` header specifying charset:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

And also add [`<meta />`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696499/meta-charset-utf-8-vs-meta-http-equiv-content-type) tag with charset:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: can you read my comment above and recommend what can i do, please?

Comment: @Kstro21 added part on conversion

Answer (score 1):

Check that your files are encoded with UTF-8 without BOM. Ensure that your PHP is using UTF-8 by setting:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

If the result is coming in from an external source, such as a DB, check the charset/collation there. That's a start. Also check whether the original string includes the proper character, or does it have that gibberish.