# How to save text field input to table as utf8 encoded data automatically?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

How to save text field input into mytable as utf8 encoded data, since textarea input automatically changing into utf8 encoded data,

Comment: You should make sure you're using the correct charset in your page. Set the `<meta charset="utf-8">` in your header. The table in your database should of course also have a utf-8 encoding.

Comment: yes, i have added, <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />, then i too the same problem existing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET NAMES utf8;
```

That will set the next queries to be saved AS UTF-8. Execute it before your actual INSERT or UPDATE

Be warned that if the sending page has a different charset, it would lead to character encoding errors.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure that your database table is set to character set UTF-8.

Secondly, set the page your are submitting data from as UTF-8 with the following meta tag:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```

Then when making your connection to the database you can execute the following query to set any subsequent queries to the UTF-8 character set too:

```
query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

See: 
[SET NAMES utf8 in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159434/set-names-utf8-in-mysql)
and http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_charset.asp