# UTF8 mysql encoded database, but not showing special characters in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, utf

I have a database with `utf_general_ci` encoding in MySQL, when I insert data in Navicat or PhpMyAdmin and do queries there, the special characters are returned fine.

But in a php variable they are showing like this:

[image: how they show]

My database and collations:

[image: database]

and in my html doc if it is a normal

it shows the characters OK, it only not work when is a php variable

please help me

Comment: show us how you get these rows and how used php variable? i guess that you not did `"SET NAMES UTF8"` or `charset=UTF-8`

Comment: you need to have the SAME encoding throughout, including on the html page itself.

Comment: look into `htmlspecialchars` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php and `htmlentities` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: if i do set names utf8 it works, but ive never done that before and was working..

Comment: `<?php echo $usuario['usu_apellido2']; ?>` where i print it and `$rows = array();
        $res  = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM usuario u, rol r WHERE u.rol_id=r.rol_id');
        
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
        
        return $rows;` @JasonOOO

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159434/set-names-utf8-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hei,

Firstly be sure you have this meta in html  tag

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

You can check also with this line in php, above you mysql extraction

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

If you store your special character in database as html code like this `&#39;` which is `'` when you extract try to use this php function

```
htmlspecialchars_decode($your_text_from_db);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
$variable = utf8_encode($valueCommingFromDB);
```

Comment: thanks, that works but i dont want to do it at every single variable i will be printing =(

Answer (score 1):

It's important to note that utf8 in mysql is fairly limited, especially utf8_general_ci. You might want to switch to utf8_unicode_ci or utf8mb4

[What's the difference between utf8_general_ci and utf8_unicode_ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci)

http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4