# Not able to insert few characters in mysql

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, laravel-5.5

Am doing a CSV import in laravel, For a few languages, it is not possible to import.  The error which I got was

Incorrect string value: '\xFCr M\xE4n...' for column 'product_name_german' at row 1

when i print the line it shows like below text (with a starting character "b") :

```
b"Laufschuhe für Männer Artikel 001"
```

Actual text which i give was

```
Laufschuhe f�r M�nner Artikel 001
```

The CSV file is utf-8 bom encoded type

Comment: Obligatory read: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF8 mysql encoded database, but not showing special characters in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19281747/utf8-mysql-encoded-database-but-not-showing-special-characters-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly be sure you have this meta in html  tag

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

You can check also with this line in php, above you mysql extraction

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

If you store your special character in database as html code like this `&#39;` which is `'` when you extract try to use this php function

```
htmlspecialchars_decode($your_text_from_db);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think u havent changed charset to utf8, try this : hope it helps #sayNoToWar

```
$statSQL= 'SET CHARACTER SET utf8'; 

mysqli_query($your_db,$sSQL) 
or die ('charset in DB didn\'t change');
```