# why do I need mb_convert_encoding to show the correct characters

Tags: php, html, mysql, encoding, mb-convert-encoding

my website have charset=UTF-8, and mysql DATABASE is also set to be UTF-8 encoding.

my problem is that when I retrieve text from mysql to the website, i need to use php function mb_convert_encoding(@db_field,'utf-8','iso-8859-1') to show the text properly. it looks like that system think mysql DB is in iso-8859-1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run this right after you connect to the database:

```
mysqli_query("SET NAMES utf8"); /* or mysql_query */
```

It is not enough to set the collation of the table to UTF-8, you also need to specify (with this query) the encoding that should be used *during the communication* between PHP and the MySQL server.
More details here: [SET NAMES utf8 in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159434/set-names-utf8-in-mysql)

Ensuring UTF-8 compatibility everywhere is tricky; my UTF-8 checklist is as follows:

- Make sure every source file is saved as UTF-8
- Ensure `<meta charset="UTF-8" />` is present on all pages
- Make sure every database table is set to use UTF-8
- Run `SET NAMES utf8` after connecting to the database
- Call `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8")` at the beginning of the script and use `mb_` string functions where possible

Comment: Thank you so much, it really solved my problem. but I don't understand why it is necessary to run this function. even that mysql db is already set to be utf8? but thanks a lot, it working now :)

Comment: It is not enough to set the collation of the table to UTF-8, you also need to specify the encoding that should be used by PHP and the MySQL server *during their communication*. Added this to my answer.