# collation/character set should I use for English and Spanish?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, phpmyadmin, content-type

I have a website with English and Spanish articles..
I have my character set `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`
 and mySQL phpAdmin table set to `utf8_general_ci`, but i am getting characters that are messed up such as `Ã³` in

> **Andrea El JabÃ³N Y La Pasta Dental**

From here [What MySQL collation/character set should I use for English and Spanish? it is suggested to us `utf8_latin_ci` but
 i dont see the option to slect `utf8_latin_ci` in phpMyAdmin.. 
I have MySQL Server version: 5.1.70-cll, phpMyAdmin 4.0.5

Comment: Where do the messed up characters occur? In the PHP output, i.e. your actual website or within the PHPMyAdmin (or equivalent MySQL UI)? In case of the former you may want to post your connection string stripped of any sensitive data such as user/pw/location.

Comment: messed up character is inside mySQL database. connection code is:
`$connection = mysql_connect($DB_HOST_dest, $DB_USER_dest, $DB_PASSWORD_dest, false)  
  //mysql_set_charset('utf8',$connection );
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL" . mysql_error()); 
  $db_found = mysql_select_db($DB_NAME_dest);`
What would be the best way to convert? find and replace inside database of changing table collation?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the wrong characters are inside the database itself. Fix them manually. Concerning the connection, I strongly advise switching to `mysqli` (see [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)) (or `PDO`, see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)) if possible. The UTF-8 encoding itself is fine – no need to switch to latin subsets.

Other than that as far as I remember a proper connection with utf-8 should be opened something like this:

```
$dbConnection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);
mysql_select_db($dbName, $dbConnection);
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $dbConnection);
mysql_query('SET NAMES "utf8"');
```

This should select the correct database encoding locally, i.e. make sure PHP expects UTF-8 encoded data (`mysql_set_charset`) and also make sure that the database understands that it has to accept UTF-8 encoded data (`SET NAMES "utf8"`) (explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159434/set-names-utf8-in-mysql)).

You should also make sure that your PHP application sends header information about your encoding `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`.

Comment: Thanks @Nikolas
This fixed my problem in wordpress 
`//define(‘DB_CHARSET’, ‘utf8′); 
   //define(‘DB_COLLATE’, ”);`
or
`define('DB_CHARSET', 'iso-8859-1');`

[http://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/how-to-fix-the-character-encoding-problem-in-wordpress-1480][1]

[1]: http://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/how-to-fix-the-character-encoding-problem-in-wordpress-1480  It seems utf8 was the one creating the problem.