# Encodings doesn't work when using insert to mySQL, ä (&auml;) turns in to Ã¤(&Atilde;&curren;)

Tags: php, mysql, iso, utf

I've encountered an extremely hard problem.
I have programmed a community on localhost with xampp on windows. When I exported it to my webserver (centos, apache2, php newest version, mysql newest) I can no longer add news with å ä ö. Everything else works, everything in language.php (translation file) with å ä ö and it appears as å ä ö on the website. But the editor in news/comments submits å ä ö as å, ä and ö. Then it would have been such as "Snö är fint" and on the website shown as "Snö är fint".

Now, it is added into the database as "SnÃ¶ Ã¤r fint" and appears as "SnÃ¶ Ã¤r fint" . I have not changed anything in the files, and have configured php and centos uses sv_SE.UTF-8.

What is the correct solution? One presumes you there's something wrong with encodings somewhere on the server, but I have configured it to use UTF-8 and mysql should use UTF-8 (although it does not say å ä ö in the database, but only ä or now in this case Ã¤), and I have the same settings I used on my own computer (the XAMPP server), where it works without problems. So that means that it's when i insert in to the database it turns to Ã¤ etc instead of ä

TLDR; After changing from my local XAMPP server to a centos server I got this problem: When I publish news or comments on the news with the letter "ä" (and å/ö) Ã¤ is shown instead of  ä as it should do and as it did on my XAMPP server. Everything on my centos server is utf-8 even the locales (sv_SE.utf8 / sv_SE.UTF-8).

Never encountered this problem during my 8 year I've coded php. And you'd think I should have enough knowledge to fix it...

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance !

Comment: Reference http://stackoverflow.com/q/279170/46675

Answer (score 1):

You must also set the encoding of the *connection* between PHP and MySQL.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Could you please be more specific?

Comment: @user3430325 see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159434/set-names-utf8-in-mysql

Comment: @feeela this did not solve my issue.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe if you remove the PHP server from main, and set it to off. Instead you should have the MySQL array as a 5.4 list, worked for me :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).