# changing text encoding in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, sql-update

I had a mysql database in which I saved some special characters `é` , but in the database it was saved like this Ã©, later on I realised that it is due to the encoding and I changed the encoding scheme for my table and DB to `UTF-8` but the text already inserted in it didn't changed,

My question is

- Is there a way to automatically change all the content to 'obey' UTF-8 .
- Is there a way that I can alteast update `Ã© to é?`

NOTE: I know about the update command , but I dont think that will help here with characters with in the field.

Comment: @KirenSiva the problem is with existing data, the question you are referring is telling when the user wants to create a new DB

Comment: Check the encoding for the individual columns, altering a table does not automatically convert the character set of the columns contained in the table, just like altering the charset of the DB does not convert the tables.

Comment: Found something [here](https://docs.moodle.org/23/en/Converting_your_MySQL_database_to_UTF8) from Moodle documentation which sounds like the correct procedure for your case.

Comment: Check [this thread][1] - more about utf8, conversions etc.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159434/set-names-utf8-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

I had some similar problems.

You need to set the encoding to utf-8 in:

- the html or php file
- the database column
- and the database connection

From what you have said you already set the encoding in the database column.

To change the database connection use `mysqli_set_charset ($conn, 'UTF-8');`

If all of these are set to UTF-8 the data should display correctly.

Comment: @SmartMindx I think you should be fine by setting the three parts to UTF-8. The times I've tried it it worked. Let me know if you have a problem though and I'll try to help you.. :)

Comment: my only prblem is wirth the existing data inside the db, I want to change that data

Comment: @SmartMindx Run the following SQL command for all your tables: `ALTER TABLE mytable CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8`