# Wrong encoding with MySql

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I have a mysql table structure like this

```
CREATE TABLE `table_contenu` (
  `id_contenu` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `id_rubrique` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `id_membre` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `id_contenu_type` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `titre_fr` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `titre_en` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `resume_fr` text NOT NULL,
  `resume_en` text NOT NULL,
  `texte_fr` text NOT NULL,
  `texte_en` text NOT NULL,
  `date_start` date NOT NULL,
  `date_end` date NOT NULL,
  `calendrier` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'false',
  `une` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'false',
  `ordre` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `flag` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'true',
  `date_maj` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

On my web site I have a form to submit data

The Charset on my page is `<meta charset="utf-8">`
and 'texte_fr' has the Collocation utf8_general_ci (I tried with utf8_unicode_ci but it's the same !)

Why when I submit the word '**séances**' this word looks '**sÃ©ances**' in the data base ?

Thanks for your help...

Comment: 1. The SQL-connection can be set to a specific charset (different depending on which API you are using - `mysqli_` or PDO?). 2. PHP header needs to be set, too: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`.

Comment: Please post your db code because it could be you aren't setting the collation via php: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159434/set-names-utf8-in-mysql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's important that your *entire* line code has the same charset to avoid issues where characters displays incorrectly.

Here's a little list of things that has to be set to a specific charset.

**Headers**

- Setting the charset in both HTML and PHP headers to UTF-8

  - PHP: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`
    *(PHP headers has to be placed before any kind output (echo, whitespace, HTML))*

**Connection**

- You also need to specify the charset in the *connection itself*.

  - **PDO** (specified in the object itself):
    `$handler = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET CHARACTER SET UTF8"));`
  - **MySQLi**:  (placed directly after creating the connection)
    *  For OOP: `$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");`
    * For procedural: `mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, "utf8");`
    *(where `$mysqli` is the MySQLi connection)*
  - **MySQL** (*depricated*, you should convert to PDO or MySQLi): (placed directly after creating the connection)
    `mysql_set_charset("utf8");`

**Database**

- Your *database* and all its tables has to be set to UTF-8. Note that charset is *not* the same as collation.

  You can do that by running the queries below *once* for each database and tables (for example in phpMyAdmin)

  `ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;`
  `ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;`

**File-encoding**

- It's also important that the `.php` file itself is UTF-8 encoded. If you're using Notepad++ to write your code, this can be done in the "Format" drop-down on the taskbar. You should use the charset `UTF-8 w/o BOM`.

You can also take a look at this StackOverflow post: [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I'm using MySql and I'm going to try your answer ;))

Comment: @Chris If you're using `mysql_`, I strongly suggest you convert to `mysqli_` or PDO for better security ;-) `mysql_` is outdated and deprecated, not to mentioned *removed completely* in PHP7.

Comment: Yes I know but before i try to solve the Charset. I just put mysql_set_charset("utf8") but now when i want to modify the data I have 'sÃ©ances' in my textarea form . How can I convert all these characters directly in the database before using mysql_set_charset("utf8")

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean - are you talking about existing values in the database, that weren't properly encoded before? You want to change those?

Comment: Yes all existing values in the database that weren't properly encoded before @Qirel !

Comment: Those were inserted with the wrong charset, so I don't think there's an easy fix to it. You could possibly create a function that selects all records, loop over them, replace the broken characters with the right one, and update those. Honestly I don't know, anything I can think of is changing them manually.

Comment: OK Thanks ! I found this https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8 and I going to loop thru all records and change them ;))