# How to set utf-8 for ajax post requests?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, utf-8

How to set `utf-8` for ajax post requests ?

i use this code for ajax post requests

```
    $.ajax({
                url: 'test.php',
                dataType: 'text',
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: form_data,                         
                type: 'post',
                success: function(php_script_response){
                $('#files_attachments_list_display').append(php_script_response);
            }
```

In `test.php`, I tried to insert data into db , ok it's insert success.

but char that insert not `utf-8`. How can i do to set utf-8 on ajax post requests ?

Answer (score 0):

You JS uses the same charset your webpage uses. So add this in your `<head>`:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Then, you need to interpret the message at your server and read as UTF-8.

---

Sorry, didn't read your question clearly. You have to set the database server field to store string as utf-8.

If you are using MySQL:

Please read this: [SET NAMES utf8 in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159434/set-names-utf8-in-mysql)

and this: [How to make MySQL handle UTF-8 properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202205/how-to-make-mysql-handle-utf-8-properly)

Comment: set `<meta charset="utf-8">` in ajax requests page or test.php ?

Comment: @mongmongmongseesee that should be in the webpage which uses the JS, that is an HTML tag.