# Can't retrieve data from mysql and display

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

now i have a function in PHP to retrieve data from my database

```php
function get_category_posts($cat_name) {
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * from posts where cat_name = '".$cat_name."' order by date desc";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $row = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < mysqli_num_rows($result); $i++) {
        $row[] = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);
    }
    return $row;
 }
```

and I have a .php file where i'm calling this function

```php
$result = get_category_posts("Актуальные новости");
foreach ($result as $row) {
    // do something
}
```

my db connection

```php
$conn=new mysqli("localhost", "ss", "ss", "s");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

db include

```php
include_once("functions.php");
```

But the problem is, nothing displayed on my file. Sorry for my bad english ^_^

Comment: Is it your exact code _blah blah blah_ ? Also did you include file before calling get_category_posts function ?

Comment: Check if Your SQL calls return some error - see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: question edited, error_log empty

Comment: can you add a `var_dump($result)` after your function call to see, what is returned?

Comment: Result of var_dump -> `array(0) { }`

Comment: You might also want to look at [`mysqli_fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) rather than building your own array in the for loop.

Comment: Are you using buffered results sets? `mysqli_num_rows` will fail if thats the case. Retrieve your result using `while(mysqli_fetch_row...`

Comment: For some reason, everybody checks for connection errors and afterwards assume that running queries can never fail. Also, your code is apparently wide open to SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this before your query

```
mysqli_query($conn, 'SET NAMES utf8');
```

Your text which you pass as a condition is not English and should be treated special so your database encoding should be utf8 and add this line in main file to call before running queries:

```
mysqli_query($conn, 'SET NAMES utf8');
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Comment: Ty so much, i don't know `mysqli_query($conn, 'SET NAMES utf8');` how it helps, but now my code it works :)

Comment: @ATIKON you can read more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159434/set-names-utf8-in-mysql