# File Transfer ASCII text

Tags: android, file-transfer

I wrote a file transfer program (The files containg ASCII characters only). One half on a Windows PC(using Visual Studio C++) and the other half on an Android tablet (using Eclipse). The files are transferring OK except that the tablet replaces certain characters with a diamond containg a question mark. One such character is the "accent a gue". How do I fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying the encoding manually while transferring. Sorry, I do not have a piece of code for you.

See here: [UTF-8 encoded html pages show � (questions marks) instead of characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445137/utf-8-encoded-html-pages-show-questions-marks-instead-of-characters)

Comment: This helps but I am still unable to send these characters to the tablet.

Answer (score 0):

android comes with three fonts.... so it dosnt know every possible character. what chars are you getting the marks on? assuming it isnt a-z or 0-9,,,, then its possible the character your passing just isnt in the font...

well if this is the case i have the answer, but as of yet cannot comment.