# HTML Special Characters converted to question mark in Chrome & Mozilla

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, google-chrome

HTML Special Characters like **á, Á** are getting converted to **?** in Chrome & Mozilla. It works fine in IE.

When I use special character á in the search box of the site, there is a difference in url for both Chrome/Mozilla and IE. Special Character in the search query is converted as:

`%E1` - in URL of Chrome/Mozilla, but in text field it is displayed as ?.

`%26aacute%3B` - in URL of IE, textfield correctly show the special character á. This is correct.

Can somebody help to fix this issue.

Site uses encoding:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to make sure your server is actually serving your pages as UTF-8.

Comment: @sevenseacat but it works in IE.

Comment: honestly, that doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Here the issue is in browsers other than IE. If it is something related to server the issue should be there in all browsers, right?

Comment: "á" is *not* a "special character" in HTML, or virtually anywhere else. You are simply not specifying your encoding handling properly all the way through, and are stumbling across browser differences in how those ambiguities are resolved.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)