# All special characters are question marks in PHP/HTML

Tags: php, character-encoding, special-characters

Php default character set is UTF-8. All special characters in PHP and HTML are outputting as question mark like "?" in the browser. All data with special characters are stored as UTF-8 in database fields. But when PHP reads the database and output to browsers, all special characters like copyright and trademark symbols are ?

Data cannot be encoding as htmlentities, because otherwise data wouldve been outputted in the browser as html code. The fields in the database have html markups. It's like a wysiwyg field.

The other similiar question didn't really solve the problem. My problem is that php is reading a database field encoded in utf-8 including html markup, text and special characters. Then save the data in another utf-8 encoded database field. But something in the middle isn't right. After the process is done, special characters in new mysql columns are ?. Thus browser is displaying ? for all special characters.

```
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbName);
mysql_set_charset('utf-8',$conn);


$categoryDescription = utf8_encode(utf8_decode($var['manufacturer_overview']));
```

Comment: HTML page must not be UTF8. Check the headers being sent on the request.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 encoded html pages show � (questions marks) instead of characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445137/utf-8-encoded-html-pages-show-%ef%bf%bd-questions-marks-instead-of-characters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had similar problem

But can be caused because of multiple reason .

1.Check if header has

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

2.Open the pages that contains Special char-set only in the Editor that supports them

3.This is what happend in my case

I was saving the data in DB using php function `utf8_encode()` but also in the database In my execute function it was already present

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$dbSelect);
```

My function looks like this

```
public function execute($sql,$useDb = 1)
    {
        if($useDb == static::LOCAL)
        {
            $dbSelect = $this->conexion;
        }elseif ($useDb == static::REMOTE) 
        {
            $dbSelect = $this->paisConexion;
        }
        mysql_set_charset('utf8',$dbSelect);
        $result = mysql_query($sql,$dbSelect) or die("ERROR: Ejecuci&oacute;n de consulta: $sql<br>\n");

        return $result;
    }
```

So it was being encoded twice I removed one and now it works fine.

Hope any of these helps

Thanks

Comment: Hi, good idea but didn't work for me. see updated question. Thanks

Comment: @user2700690 bro remove the last ecode part and try , `utf8_encode(utf8_decode` try totally removing this and add the header most probably u would have added it already .

Comment: thats what I had before. Believe it, if I remove encode and decode, data will be cut off at the first special character in the new output field in database. If I put encode then decode, at least I got all data in the new field but with ? mark instead of special characters...

Comment: This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0 http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php

Comment: @user2700690  Yeah I had the same problem Data was cutting off so to fix this after trying lot of things , Following method worked.

while saving the data I used `addslashes()` function and before printing in any html tag I used `htmlspecialchars()` it worked .

Comment: @user2700690 yes you are right ,about the deprecated part :)

Comment: This is the new one. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php looks like its making process. Instead of ? alone, now its saving special characters plus Â in front of it.

Comment: @user2700690 you will have to play around , okay keep the ecode decode function and then use the `htmlspecialchars()` also all together then try

Comment: Got it! Its actually saving the same exact data in the new database field. I just had the browser encoding hardcoded something else. Its working now. Magical! Thanks a million! Never wouldve thought I had to force mysql encode again.