# UTF-8 values displayed and stored as � (questions marks)

Tags: c#, asp.net, utf-8, character-encoding

I face a problem with my asp.net web-form portal that is Characters displayed as question marks,when the user change the encoding characters in his browser and enter Arabic or Indian text into textboxes and submit the form I see the values as question marks in **debugging** and saved as question marks in DB.

I did the following but did not fix the problem

1 I saved all file (solution files)   as utf-8.

2 added meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/ in master page.

note:my portal connected to dynamics CRM online, CRM accept all languages and all encoding characters.

problem in ASP.net web-form solution 
Please help me

Comment: I think you're going to need to provide more information.  You're stating the data entered into text boxes is being stored in the database as `?`.  What data type are the columns in the database receiving data?  are they `nvarchar`?  are you inserting into the columns as `nvarcharColumn = N'value'`?

Comment: this might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445137/utf-8-encoded-html-pages-show-%EF%BF%BD-questions-marks-instead-of-characters

Comment: You are most likely needing to set your database to use the proper collation. It is important to understand what this means as it has different implications depending what collation you use. SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS may work for you if you are using SQL Server.

Comment: I connect to dynamics crm online , the problem is not in crm or database it is in my side, when I debug I see the the question marks in debugging before inserted to database.