# UTF-8 Issue using correct meta tag

Tags: php, html, encoding, utf-8, utf

I'm using Laravel, this is probably the first time in 2 years that i've come across this problem. I'm having questionmarks in my text ( result of encoding issue's )

> ori�ntatie,

The weird thing is i'm using the correct meta tag in my head

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

I've tried different fonts, I'm also using typekit, i disabled it but the problem persists. The text is copy pasted from a photoshop design, **so no text out of the database.**

Any idea where I should start to look for a solution in my code. I'm not seeing it. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 encoded html pages show � (questions marks) instead of characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445137/utf-8-encoded-html-pages-show-questions-marks-instead-of-characters)

Comment: Is that data loading from a database?

Comment: Nope! it's just copy paste from a photoshop design

Comment: If you pasted that text from somewhere, double check that the editor you used to save the HTML is set to use UTF-8 too.

Comment: Thanks, I rewrote the words myself and the problem persists.

Comment: It was phpstorm, solution posted. Never heard of IDE's messing encoding up. thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

> PHPStorm was causing the issue.

My whole project's **File Encoding** settings were set to the wrong encoding.

To fix it you can go to

```
File - File Encoding - UTF-8
```