# Double UTF-8 encoding, but why? PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I have some forms, that insert some data into a MySQL database, and for some reason the characters get double utf-8 encoded. You don't see it on the front-end of my website, but in the back-end you do, if i look at the data from phpmyadmin, it's double encoded.

Also, to display data entered from phpmyadmin i have to `utf8_encode` it.

If i use `uft8_decode()` on my data before i put it into my database, it works, but then i'd have to use `utf8_encode()` again to display my data properly, and i would like to find a better solution that re-writing most of my code.

The characters i'm dealing with is the danish æ, ø and å characters.

I have every setting i can find in php.ini set to utf-8, every thing i can find in phpmyadmin to utf8, html meta tag set to utf-8, and still i have this error to deal with.

So my question is, does anyone know why this happens, or how i could fix it?..

**Update:** After running the mysql code Jako suggested, the data is properly encoded in the back-end of the database when it comes from the front-end, but i still need to run `utf8_encode()` to display the data properly on the front-end, any ideas?..

**Update 2:** Again, after running the code from the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650591/whether-to-use-set-names) i still had problems, the encoding was now on and off utf8, and i suspect phpmyadmin for resetting the encoding somehow. I found a new way of doing things, and it works flawlessly, described in my answer below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Okay, i found the answer!! I searched a bit more, (have been doing so for hours) and found this question: [Whether to use “SET NAMES”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650591/whether-to-use-set-names)</strike>

Using the answer from that question i ran this query:

```
mysql_query("SET character_set_client = UTF8");
mysql_query("SET character_set_results = UTF8");
mysql_query("SET character_set_connection = UTF8");
mysql_query("SET names UTF8");
```

<strike>That's it, it works fine now on all my php scripts. Still thanks to Jako for leading me in the right way. ;)</strike>

**Update:** Okay, since the encoding was on and off and the settings didn't stay that way i found a new solution that works. I added [mysql_set_charset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php) to my connection script:

```
mysql_set_charset("UTF8");
```

It gives me the right data from the database every time and inserts the right data as well, so this was only one line of code.

Comment: You should switch from the deprecated `mysql_*` interface to `mysqli_I`.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into similar issues in the past and this did the trick for me.

```
mysql_query("SET names UTF8");
```

Comment: Got me further, i realized i'd have to use this on the mysql user i use for the php connection, and now it at least doesn't get double encoded in the database, but now it doesnt get properly encoded in the frontend, so i'm half way there...

Comment: Glad I was able to help, I had the same problem before and it was so stressful trying to find the solution.