# MySQL: ucs2_slovenian_ci to utf-8 on webpage

Tags: php, mysql, encoding

I have a MySQL database with tables in ucs2_slovenian_ci encoding. I would like to write content of tables on utf-8 encoding webpage. So far I tried with:

```
mysql_set_charset ("utf-8");
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf-8'");
...
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
...
<?php echo utf8_encode($text); ?>
...
```

I'm still geting weird signs (question marks) instead of letters Š,Č,Ž
Nothing seems to work.

Weird thing is that with php command `mysql_client_encoding($link)` it says I have latin1 encoding. When I look page in Firefox it says UTF-8. What's wrong?

Please help.

Comment: `ucs2_slovenian_ci` is a database collation, while encoding is `ucs2`. You need something like `iconv("ucs-2", "utf-8", $text)`, not `utf8_encode` (which is `iconv("utf-8", "iso-latin-1", $text)`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ucs2_slovenian_ci encoding

That is not an encoding but a collation. A collation is the information on how something is sorted.

For your website, this isn't even of interest, because that's what the database knows about itself - or better: the data stored in itself.

For your website script's it's more important that you tell your database which encoding you need - here: UTF-8.

You signal that the database server by specifying the database client encoding. Consult your database client driver manual how to specify that. It could be that:

```
mysql_set_charset("utf8", $link);
```

Take care: it's `utf8` while officially it's written `UTF-8`. That's something special with the MySQL database, write `UTF-8` as `utf8` when you set that parameter.

Do not use:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf-8'");
```

because it's deprecated (not good, see as well the PHP manual and [Whether to use “SET NAMES”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650591/whether-to-use-set-names)).

And if you tell the database client which encoding you expect, you don't need to encode your own, like this:

```
utf8_encode($text);
```

Remove that stuff, you don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

First add `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

and

> mysql_set_charset ("utf-8");

should be:

> $db = mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password);
>
> mysql_set_charset ("utf8", $db);

Also make sure what in  MySQL DB everything in utf-8

Anyways you may play with:

> mb_convert_encoding($string, "Other encoding", "UTF-8");

Comment: mb_convert_encoding just ignores special charecters instead of writting them
I've already try with mysql_set_charset ("utf8"); and it doesn't work
so doesn't header... It's not problem with page itself, it's problem with data that are in database in ucs-2. Cannot change encoding in DB because I don't own it

Comment: @user1077442: You don't need to change encoding in database, because mysql does the re-encoding on the fly for you if you tell the mysql database which encoding you need, like `utf8`. It will give you `utf8`. If you break it later on your own, that's your fault. But mysql does what it was commanded to do.

Comment: Ok, now I somehow got it working. It's not perfect but now at least i can replace characters with right ones. I also noticed that htmlentities was big problem for not showing like it suposed to. Thank you all