# Special chars issue TinyMCE + PHP + AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, tinymce

The symbols are saving properly in database but while it is being displayed in the view the symbols are not displaying propely.

Data as saved in database:

```
<p>Symbol here is sigma : Σ</p>
<p>Symbol here is beta: β</p>
<p>Symbol here is omega: Ω</p>
<p>Symbol here is gamma: γ</p>
```

Data being displayed:

```
Symbol here is sigma : Î£
Symbol here is beta: Î²
Symbol here is omega: Î©
Symbol here is gamma: Î³
```

Code for fetching data:

```
public function get_questions() {
        $this->layout = false;
        if(($this->request->is('post')) && ($this->request->is('ajax'))) {
            $subject = $this->request->data['subject'];
            $chapter = $this->request->data['chapter'];
            $studentID = $this->Auth->User('PERSONROLE');
            //$phase = $subject->getPhase($subject);
            $this->Paginator->settings = array(
                'limit' => 1,
                'conditions' => array(
                    'QuestionBank.SUBJECT' => $subject, 
                    'QuestionBank.CHAPTER' => $chapter,
                    'QuestionBank.IS_ACTIVE' => 1,
                    //'QuestionBank.PHASE'
                ),
            );
            $questions = $this->paginate();
            if($questions) {
                $questions[0]['QuestionBank']['page'] = $this->request->params['paging']['QuestionBank']['page'];
                $questions[0]['QuestionBank']['current'] = $this->request->params['paging']['QuestionBank']['current'];
                $questions[0]['QuestionBank']['count'] = $this->request->params['paging']['QuestionBank']['count'];
                $questions[0]['QuestionBank']['prevPage'] = $this->request->params['paging']['QuestionBank']['prevPage'];
                $questions[0]['QuestionBank']['nextPage'] = $this->request->params['paging']['QuestionBank']['nextPage'];
                $questionID = $questions[0]['QuestionBank']['ID'];
                $selfStudyStatus = $this->_getQuestionStatus($questionID, $studentID);
                if($selfStudyStatus) {
                    $questions[0]['SelfStudyStatus'] = $selfStudyStatus['SelfStudy'];
                }

                $this->loadModel('MyNote');
                $myNote = new MyNote();
                $notes = $myNote->getPersonalNote($questionID, $studentID);
                if($notes) {
                    $questions[0]['MyNote'] = $notes['MyNote'];
                } else {
                    $questions[0]['MyNote'] = array();
                }

                $this->loadModel('Enquiry');
                $enquiry = new Enquiry();
                $enquiries = $enquiry->getEnquiries($studentID, $questionID);
                if($enquiries) {
                    $questions[0]['Enquiry'] = $enquiries;
                } else {
                    $questions[0]['Enquiry'] = array();
                }
            }
            array_walk_recursive($questions, function(&$value, $key) {
                if (is_string($value)) {
                    $value = iconv('windows-1252', 'utf-8', $value);

                }
            });
            $this->set('questions', $questions[0]);
        }
    }
```

Please check the code above and is this line "$value = iconv('windows-1252', 'utf-8', $value);" got to do something with the conversion. The charset conversion is new for me.

Comment: I'm using cakephp. In database.php 'encoding' => 'utf8' is enabled

Comment: Check the answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696619/displaying-unicode-symbols-in-html

Comment: @TareqMahmood. I've done that as well

Comment: As you see, you are viewing the symbols properly in this post. So there is nothing wrong in html. Can you show us some of your php code which processes this data?

Comment: @TareqMahmood. Followed this also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017975/converting-html-entities-to-utf-8-and-inserting-them-into-a-mysql-database