# Persian character's issue in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, persian

When I insert Persian data to database, data will save like this:  `†Ø¯Ø± 50 Ù„ÛŒØªØ±ÛŒ`

But when I read data from database and echo it on the web, they are Ok.

I need to read data in my database directly.
what is your solution?

Mysql setting:

> Server connection collation: UTF8_general_ci
>
> Html file charset is utf8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved:

in connection

```
<?php
 $dbLink = mysql_connect($argHost, $argUsername, $argPassword);
    mysql_query("SET character_set_results=utf8", $dbLink);
    mb_language('uni'); 
    mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
    mysql_select_db($argDB, $dbLink);
    mysql_query("set names 'utf8'",$dbLink);
?>
```

source:
[PHP mysql charset utf8 problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068616/php-mysql-charset-utf8-problems)

Answer (score 7):

I had a same issue,this code: `mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");` solved my problem!

Answer (score 4):

you should use this code

```
$yourConnection->set_charset("utf8");
```

for example

```
function insertUser($inUN,$inP,$inFN,$inLN,$inE,$inD)
    {   
        $servername="localhost";
        $username="mnr";
        $password="milad1373";
        $databacename="mnr01";

        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $databacename);
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 
        $conn->set_charset("utf8");

        $sql = "INSERT INTO chuser (username, passWord, fname,lname,email,date)
        VALUES ('$inUN', '$inP','$inFN','$inLN', '$inE','$inD')";
        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }

        $conn->close();
    }
```

i had this problem but it resolved by this code
and for more information go to [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have executed

```
SET character_set_results=utf8

SET NAMES 'utf8'
```

before you send any `INSERT` command.

Have a look at this question for more information. I think it may help;

- [UTF8 All The Way Through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 0):

You should change your collation to `utf8_unicode_ci` in your phpmyadmin:

1. Go you your localhost/phpmyadmin
2. Select your database
3. Next to your database there's an small icon click on that
4. Click on change
5. Change your collation to `utf8_unicode_ci`.
6. Insert this code to your php file.

> ```
> if (!$connection->set_charset("utf8")) {
>     printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
>     exit();
> } else {
>     printf("Current character set: %s\n", $connection->character_set_name());
> }
> ```