# Some characters(μ) showing as ??.php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Iam trying to read a data from mysql database. In my db i checked the data is showing as `'μ'` and charset is properly set to `'UTF-8'`. But when in PHP when i ran this below code, the output `'μ'` is showing as `'?'`. I tried so many ways by adding different types of charsets and all in the scripts, but all in vain, still its showing as `'?'`. Can anyone pls help me with it.

My script is below:

```
<?php
  ini_set("default_charset", "UTF-8");
  header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);

  $tender_id=$_GET['tender_id'];

  include('config_sqli.php');
?>
<?php
  $result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM comparitive_st_sup WHERE 
                      id='$member[$x]' and tender_id='$tender_id'");
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

  $prod_description1 = $row['prod_description'];
  $prod_description = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $prod_description1);
  }
  echo $prod_description;
  echo '<br>';
?>
```

Comment: try utf8_encode:http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

Comment: i saw something like $value = utf8_encode($value); I tried to implement in my code but its showing ?? only. Need to check what is the exact problem.

Comment: You need to set the encoding in `mysql` as well. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068616/php-mysql-charset-utf8-problems

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: When displaying HTML use `htmlspecialchars` and not SQL escaping. You also want to move that `echo $prod_description` inside the loop, or remove the loop entirely and just fetch once.

Comment: Thank you for the info @tadman. Appreciate that. Surely implement that.

Comment: `UTF8` is ***not*** the correct character set for MySQL, you want to be using `UTF8mb4`. Please [read this to found out why](http://stackoverflow.com/q/279170/3536236)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this,

Run below query before executing actual query:

```
mysqli_query($con, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

OR

try this your mysqli connection

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8"); 
// be careful, this method can be not working (mantainers builds bugs for old php releases), first example is works fine
```

i hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Perfect. Its working well. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: A small doubt . How to use mysqli_query($con, "SET NAMES 'utf8'"); with  mysql_query. i mean without mysqli

Comment: use this with mysql : mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");