# I can only get `mb_convert_encoding` to work locally, or something is cancelling the effect

Tags: php, wordpress, encoding, utf-8

I'm converting some `the_content()` in wordpress to UTF-8, this line works fine locally.

```
$html = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
```

And all of my text comes out as normal.

When I go live I get character encoding problems, it's as thought `mb_convert_encoding` is no longer working, or something else is causing my encoding problems.

For instance a £ symbol outputs "Â£".

They are using the same database, but I've converted the live one to `utf8_unicode_cli` anyway, I have `meta charset="utf-8"` I have `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` placed in my `functions.php` and on my `single.php`.

I'm not sure what else could be interfering.

Comment: What output do you get, and what were you expecting?

Comment: And those *"character encoding problems"* manifest themselves how?

Comment: @LinusKleen sorry, edited.

Comment: @ChrisWesseling Hi sorry, yea just edited, I get "Â£" instead of just "£"

Comment: Might be the hosting provider disabled it ?

Comment: Looks like your live database was utf-8 to begin with and is converted twice.

Comment: @iamsleepy I am on aws so it might be a setting somewhere?

Comment: @ChrisWesseling It was doing this before I did the conversion, `SHOW FULL TABLES COLUMN` was showing `latin1_swedish` so I converted it to utf-8 and still the problem persisted.

Comment: How did you convert? I think you've only been changing the collation. If you've been sending utf8 to mysql while it didn't expect it, it will have interpreted the to bytes '\xc2\xa3' as 2 characters "Â£" instead of the single "£". Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1650591/383793).