# Special characters in mySQL (and php) - THE BASICS

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I am confused! Recently my webhotel **updated php** and now my old tables render special characters differently (wrongly).
Both my **tables and my input/output-php-pages are set to utf-8** and since this update, also the inputs from php are treated differently; now my special characters are being utf-8-encoded as they enter the database. So since this change, when I review tables within phpMyAdmin, the old inserts have the original (non-encoded) special characters - the new posts have utf-8-encoded charcters (also special).

So what I would like to do is rewrite input and output to insert and show non-encoded characters - but I am not sure if this is possible without skipping utf-8 entirely (in php and mySQL). But **is there an utf-8- way to submit non-encoded characters?**

AND - perhaps more fundamentally - I need to understand what the possible downsides are. I am using Danish characters in and out and I'm not going to use any other language (for this project). So if it IS possible to insert and output non-encoded characters using utf-8 - **am I then going to have unexpected/destructive issues?**

I have read a lot of posts regarding php/mySQL/special characters but I haven't seen this angle on the issue yet. Hope I am not duplicating
I hope not because it has been working very nicely until the update.

Comment: If you have a DB for testning, I would try [mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php). I would recommend to only try this in the test-DB before you know it works..

Comment: I don't have a testing db - but possbily I might need one for this reason. Undecided yet. But thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you are using only Danish characters, you may as well go utf8 all the way.

There are *many* places where the encoding needs to be stated:

- The  at the top of the html
- The columns in the database (column CHARACTER SET defaults from table, which defaults from database)
- The encoding in your PHP code.

When you `CREATE TABLE`, tack on `DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8`.  If you have existing tables, without that, speak up; we may need to deal with them.
If you want Danish collation, the specify `COLLATION utf8_danish_ci`, too.  Then (if I recall correctly), `aa` will sort after `z`.
(The default is `utf8_general_ci`, which won't do that sorting.)
Figure out what encoding you have (or can get) in your php code.  If you have some text with accents in it, do this:

```
$hex = unpack('H*', $text);
echo implode('', $hex)
```

If you have utf8, å will be `C3A5`, for latin1 it will be `E5`.

Regardless of what encoding in in the tables, you must call set_charset('utf8') or set_charset('latin1') depending on what encoding is in the data in PHP.  MySQL will gladly transcode between latin1 and utf8 as things are passed between PHP and MySQL.  For different APIs:

```
⚈  mysql: mysql_set_charset('utf8');
⚈  mysqli: $mysqli_obj->set_charset('utf8');
⚈  PDO: $db = new PDO('dblib:host=host;dbname=db;charset=UTF-8', $user, $pwd);
```

For much more info, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll .

Comment: With `utf8_danish_ci`, these sort after `z`, in the clumps shown:  `Ä=Æ=ä=æ  Ö=Ø=ö=ø  Aa=Å=å  Þ=þ`

Comment: Well, what I am really asking is; is there a way to store the actual special characters in db using utf-8. What I am getting now is "Ã¦" instead of æ, "Ã˜" instead of "Ø", etc.
This seems stupid to me; I am getting different special characters inserted into db **when I would rather have "my own" special characters inserted**. As I see it you are guiding me to work with (and accept) the utf-encoded char's but I would only like to do that IF I AM CONVINCED THAT IT SERVES A FEASIBLE/REASONABLE PURPOSE - OR IF IT IS UNAVOIDABLE?

Comment: (It is a common problem, and it is fixable.)  The utf8 encoding for `Ø` is hex `C398`.  But when that hex is interpreted as latin1, it comes out `Ã˜`.  So, the problem is that PHP had bytes in one encoding, but the transmission to/from MySQL was assuming a different encoding.  That inconsistency led to an error either on INSERTion or on SELECTing.  Do `SELECT HEX(col) ...` to see what is in the table.  Then we can pursue where the 'bug' lies.  My blog covers the problem and too much more:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll .  I have provided tidbits of it in this thread.

Comment: Sorry - haven't had much time to read up on your blog. But I intend to. So far, many thanks for elaborate answer. But perhaps you could answer me this: when I look into my database, via mySQL, and I see my desired special characters displaying correctly (those inserted before update) - are they actually formatted correctly (c398, etc.) and then presented the right way beacuse the phpMyAdmin-page is build the _right way_ - and my own front end is flawed? OR! Am I supposed to see the utf-8-encoding when I check phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Right. I read up on the blog, but too many unknowns for me. When I investigated further on "SET NAMES" I saw several warnings about that and stumbled upon recommendations ([stackoverflow-1650591](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650591/whether-to-use-set-names/1650834#1650649)) to use `mysql_set_charset('utf8', $link)`. **When I tried that something happened that seems to have affected ALL MY PHP-pages** so the old inserts show correctly, and only the few recent look wrong (the false _latino_-special characters). Not sure if the problem is solved for good - but it's working at the moment...

Comment: When I read thru your answer again, I realised that you suggested exactly the same -. only I didn't know what it meant when I read it the first time.   
Now it jumps in my eye: ⚈  mysql: `mysql_set_charset('utf8');` Thanks a bunch

Comment: See also `bin2hex()`.