# PHP. JSON encode utf-8

Tags: php, json, encoding, utf-8

Turkish character problem. I'm using PHP 5.4 version.
Php page

```
<?php

mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","android_project","mypassword");

mysql_select_db("android_project");
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8_turkish_ci'");
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product");

while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
{

$output[]= $e;

}
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf8_turkish_ci");
print(json_encode($output)); 
mysql_close();

?>
```

Akıllı=Ak?ll? , 
Hafıza=Haf?za

etc.

Comment: Have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650591/whether-to-use-set-names

Comment: `utf8_turkish_ci` is not an *encoding*, it's merely a collation. Use `utf8` for MySQL and `UTF-8` everywhere else.

Comment: Thaks for answer.its work.

Answer (score -1):

Check if your file has been saved with utf8, then try again