# PHP json_encode is not working

Tags: php, json

I am having a **users** table with **Collation as utf8_general_ci**. Having fields like name, age, phone and email.

It seems some of the rows of name field is having some trailing spaces. If echo-ed `echo "selectedUser " . $selectedUser->name`; It is printing that name with spaces and I just copied the name from DB field and pasted it on a php file, and echo-ed that text, it was printing like

> selectedUser "Rohan Harish Reddy\u00a0\u00a0"

name field contains only trailing white-spaces on the field, I am not sure

> why it is printed like this ? Why it is not working for json_encode ?
>   How can I convert this **user** object with json_encode ?

**Code:**

```
$users = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

foreach ($users as $user) { 

    $selectedUser = $user;

    echo "selectedUser " . json_encode($selectedUser);

}
```

If add below code above the fetch all statement, It is working fine.

```
$this-> adminConn ->query("SET NAMES utf8");
$stmt = $this-> adminConn ->query($sql);
```

> Do I need to set "SET NAMES utf8" for each query ? Is there a common
>   way to achieve it ?

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't have spaces (Unicode 0x0020), you have non-breaking spaces (Unicode 0x00A0). JSON standard ([RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-7)) declares that all Unicode characters may be escaped, and `json_encode` is using this to escape the non-breaking spaces (to distinguish them to a human reader from normal spaces, I would assume). The solution is probably to figure out why you have trailing non-breaking spaces in your data.

Comment: When we upload csv files, It is happening.  Unicode 0x00A0 is inserted. Any way to avoid it while parsing the uploaded file and avoiding it on json_encode ??

Comment: I don't know what your CSV looks like, or how you are parsing it, or how you sanitise (or not) your values. Avoiding it on `json_encode` is simple, just replace all nbsps with regular spaces, or delete them outright, using `preg_replace`, before `json_encode`.

Comment: If name is having any non-breaking spaces, that particular object is not printed with json_encode($selectedUser) due to this non-breaking spaces.

Comment: I do not want to replace that non-breaking spaces, Whatever content that is available on the DB fields need to be returned. If add below code above the fetch all statement, It is working fine.

$this-> adminConn ->query("SET NAMES utf8");
$stmt = $this-> adminConn ->query($sql);
Do I need to set "SET NAMES utf8" for each query ? Is there a common way to achieve it ?

Comment: If you need a JSON representation of the exact content in the database, then you have the correct value - `"Rohan Harish Reddy\u00a0\u00a0"` is a valid JSON for a string with two trailing nbsps. I suppose I do not understand your question. (You might also read through [answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650591/whether-to-use-set-names) to see arguments why `SET NAMES utf8` is generally not a good idea.)