# problem to show data mysql to json with php

Tags: php, mysql, json

i have a Persian data base that use collection utf8-general-ci but when i run below code i face with ???? instated of Persian words .

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "testinsta");
$result = $conn->query("SELECT m_1, m_2, m_3 FROM codecode");
mysqli_query($conn, "SET NAMES utf8");
$outp = "";
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  if ($outp != "") {$outp .= ",";}
  $outp .= '{"Name":"'  . $rs["m_1"] . '",';
  $outp .= '"City":"'   . $rs["m_2"]        . '",';
  $outp .= '"Country":"'. $rs["m_3"]     . '"}';
}
$outp ='{"records":['.$outp.']}';
$conn->close();
echo($outp);
?>
```

mysql to json with php problem

[image: mysql to json with php problem]

Comment: Don't manually build json. Build an array and use `json_encode()` to convert it into json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this,

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "testinsta");
$conn->set_charset("utf8");
```

and remove below line,

```
mysqli_query($conn, "SET NAMES utf8");
```

and now check.

Here is brief details about [Whether to use “SET NAMES”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650591/whether-to-use-set-names).